# PageView with horizontal, non-filled children

Tags: flutter

It appears that `PageView` will always fill according to the axis of the scrolling. What would be the best approach to cater for "peeking" in a `PageView`?

I tried implementing a `PageView.custom` with the standard `SliverChildListDelegate` but I'm guessing that doesn't allow for arbitrary / custom sizing. I was going to start doing something custom but decided asking here is a good first start.

See the image below for an example of what I'm trying to achieve.

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This feature is [added in 3 Mar 2017](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/8539). After [@EricSeidel's request](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/8408).

This can achieve by [controller](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/PageView/controller.html) property of [PageView](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/PageView-class.html).

```
controller: PageController(
  initialPage: 1,
  viewportFraction: 0.8,
),
```

[PageController.viewportFraction](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/PageController/viewportFraction.html) to peek previous and next.
[PageController.initialPage](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/PageController/initialPage.html) to display middle page when app is launched.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(LimeApp());

class LimeApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Lime',
      home: MainPage(),
    );
  }
}

class MainPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
          vertical: 50.0,
        ),
        child: PageView(
          controller: PageController(
            initialPage: 1,
            viewportFraction: 0.8,
          ),
          children: [
            Container(margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10.0,), color: Colors.redAccent),
            Container(margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10.0,), color: Colors.purpleAccent),
            Container(margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10.0,), color: Colors.greenAccent)
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I couldn't figure out a better way to add margin between pages and how to avoid space after last and start page.

[image]

Comment: @Luke do you know a better way to add margin between pages?

Comment: You can use `PageView.builder` to check the item `index` and omit the margin for the first and last items.

Answer (score 6):

My understanding is that this is not possible with the current PageView, I've turned this into an issue: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/8408